# Boot from CD triggers Bitlocker

Tags: windows-8.1, bitlocker, partition-recovery

using Paragon, I have deleted the recovery partition.
Afterwards, Windows 8.1 would not boot anymore.
Then I tried booting from a Partition [Manager CD](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html), but when I try to boot from the CD, the Bitlocker Manager kicks it and asks my for a recovery key (which I don't have because I entered some garbage mail during the setup process).

I would like to ask why the Bitlocker kicks it. When I try to boot from the CD, the file system shouldn't be accessed, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitlocker can be associated with the BIOS and is often associated with the onboard TPM chip. These do not require a filesystem to get things going.

If you don't have your recovery key, it's unlikely you'll be able to recover this system. Its likely that the partition you deleted included the necessary bits to initialize Bitlocker, including authentication, for booting from the Bitlocker encrypted drive. It's also likely that the bios recognizes that you have a Bitlocker encrypted drive.

It may be necessary to disconnect the drive before you'll be able to boot the computer. If your computer and HDD support hot swapping, you may be able to just plug in the drive and mount it after booting the system. If not, you'll need something that supports hot swapping such as a USB-to-SATA adapter.